# Extract raster values to points in GEE

Tags: google-earth-engine

I would like to extract raster values by points from MOD09A1, and finally get the time serise of NIRv from 2000 to 2023. I've uploaded my points in GEE assets including 909 points. I tried to use the code below, and save the NIRv time serise to 'csv' files. The problem is that the output csv only have the data in one date rather than a time serise, and it only have 500 points data not 900 points.

```
var roi:Table users/zhangjrCA/China
var MOD09A1:Imagecollection MODIS/061/MOD09A1
var table:Table users/zhangjrCA/Data

var startdate = '2000-01-01';
var enddate = '2023-12-31';

var MOD09A1data = MOD09A1.filterDate(startdate,enddate)
                  .filterBounds(roi)
                  .map(Clip_ROI)
                  .map(CalNirv);

var NIRv = MOD09A1data.select('NIRv');
var NIRvimage = NIRv.first();
print(NIRvimage);

//Extracting values
var sampled_points = NIRvimage.sampleRegions({ //--> or should I use 'reduceRegions'? If that makes more sence, what would the code look like for  'reduceRegions'?
  collection: Points,
  scale: 50,
  geometries: true
});

// Export features, specifying corresponding names.
Export.table.toDrive(sampled_points,
"sampled_points", //my task
"GEE_Folder", //my export folder
"sampled_points",  //file name
"CSV");

print(MOD09A1data)                  
Map.addLayer(MOD09A1data,{min:0,max:1},'nirv')
Map.addLayer(Points)

function CalNirv(image) {
  var nirv = image.normalizedDifference(['sur_refl_b02', 'sur_refl_b01']).multiply(image.select('sur_refl_b02').divide(10000)).rename('NIRv');
  return image.addBands(nirv);
}

function Clip_ROI(image){
  return image.clip(roi)
}
```

Comment: Please [Edit] the Question to provide more than "it still didn't work." *How* didn't it work? *What* did it do instead?

Answer (score 0):

I have written an example regarding to your problem. Please check it out:
https://code.earthengine.google.com/276df38081c6bb171cea5865c010d195

```
Map.centerObject(table);

var ndvi = imageCollection.select('NDVI')
.filterDate('2020','2022')

print(
  ui.Chart.image.seriesByRegion(ndvi, table, ee.Reducer.first(),
  'NDVI', 1000, 'system:time_start', 'point_id')
  )
```